# Where does Audacity keep a user's configuration files?

Tags: linux, audacity, file-location

I've just installed [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) on SLED 11, from the Education repository if it matters.  I'm trying to set some defaults, but need to know where the audacity configuration files live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Audacity Manual](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Preferences#Where_are_Preferences_stored.3F)

> Audacity Preferences are stored in a
>   configuration file called
>   audacity.cfg. It is a text file and
>   can be edited with any text editor.
>   The file is stored at:
>
> - Windows: Documents and Settings\user name\Application Data\Audacity\audacity.cfg
> - OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/audacity/audacity.cfg
> - Linux: ~/.audacity-data/audacity.cfg